# How to replace the 3rd character and multiple of 3 's character in a string with a \n in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like `'oeew9w79WMIGL'`. I want to get an output like below,

```
oee
w9w
79W
MIG
L
```

How to do it with plain *JavaScript*?

Comment: This is not "replace". This is insert.

Comment: Use regex to capture three or less consecutive alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I don't think so, as OP is converting `79W` to `79w`

Comment: @Weedoze again, I don't think it is, as the OP isn't inserting, but is replacing. The question seems to be more about splitting the string into an array.

Comment: @evolutionxbox OP is not replacing. OP is adding `\n` every 3 characters

Comment: Ah. Right, that's not an array... sigh. I'm tired this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use regex

```js
let str = 'oeew9w79WMIGL';

document.write(str.match(/.{1,3}/g));
```

Comment: Thanks for ur one liner

Answer (score 2):

You could replace a part of the string.

```js
var string = 'oeew9w79WMIGL';

console.log(string.replace(/.../g, '$&\n'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your one liner approach. Both of you and @Viking code are right.. But I can't tick two solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var foo = "oeew9w79WMIGL";
$('#test').html(foo.match(/.{1,3}/g).join("<br />") );
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">
</span>
```

```
 var str= "oeew9w79WMIGL";
console.log( str.match(/.{1,3}/g).join("<br />") );
```

Comment: he asked plain js not JQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
 each_slice = function(enm, slice_size) {
   var results = [];
     slice_size = (slice_size < 1 ? 1 : slice_size ); 
       for (var i=0; i<=enm.length; i=i+3) {
         results.push(enm.slice(i, i+3));
      }
  return results;
}

var x = "oeew9w79WMIGL";
each_slice(x,3).join("\n")

//oee
//w9w
//79W
//MIG
//L
```

for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41219012/4481312